# Serialize "JsValue" in Jint

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, jint

At the moment, I'm trying to figure out how to save a Jint.NET JavaScript environment to file, so I can load it again later.

However, I'm having major trouble trying to serialize/deserialize the `Jint.Native.JsValue` class. Since it has no constructor, Newtonsoft doesn't like deserializing to it, and when serializing, it ignores all private properties, resulting in only the `Type` field being saved.

```
string saved = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someJsValue);  //output: {Type: x}
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsValue>(saved); //error: no constructor
```

Is there any way around this so I can load/save this properly?

Comment: I think you should use the ToDictionary() method on the JsValue object to convert it into Key - Value pair once done you may then parse it likewise.

Comment: There is no `ToDictionary()` method for generic `JsValue` classes? At least not in my case.

Comment: You'll need to implement a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to solve this.

Comment: What is `JsValue`? Is it an abstract class? Is it  part of a framework you can't edit? Please provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @AndréSanson As made quite clear by the tag and question title, this is the class **included in Jint,** `Jint.Native.JsValue`.

Comment: There is a way to make newtonsoft serialize private fields but I don't know how to construct the `JsValue` back from the json. I believe a better way is to create your own configuration class (`MyJsValueConfiguration`) and save this configuration on a file and use it in a factory to create the `JsValue`.